# variables from JS showing up when HTML is viewed as literal names of variables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

The problem is that when  we use a certain part of our code, the message appears on the HTMl with little problem, the problem, is that when those variables are changed, things fall appart and instead of getting the assigned value of our variables we get a litteral

> {{s1}}

and unchanging color values. We need to have the javascript switching between "está and "no está" and the boxes to change color from red to the shade of green you see in the javascript.

Here's a little sample code, first the HTML in question

```
<center>
    Tarjeta: {{idt}}, Version: {{ver}}
    <table border="1px" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=400>
            <center>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor={colors1}><h2>{{s1}}</h2></td>
            <td bgcolor={colors2}><h2>{{s2}}</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor={colors3}><h2>{{s3}}</h2></td>
            <td bgcolor={colors4}><h2>{{s4}}</h2></td>
        </tr>
            </center>
    </table>
</center>
```

and the javascript that feeds that HTML. We need the commented part to become the one that feeds the code above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MainCtrl($scope)
    {
        $scope.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

        $scope.socket.on("message", function(data) {

            $scope.$apply(function()
                {
            $scope.idt = data.idt;
            $scope.ver = data.ver;

            $scope.s1 = data.s1;
            $scope.s2 = data.s2;
            $scope.s3 = data.s3;
            $scope.s4 = data.s4;

            $scope.colors1 = "red";
            $scope.colors2 = "red";
            $scope.colors3 = "red";
            $scope.colors4 = "red";

            /*Mejorar este codigo
            if (data.s1 == 1){
                $scope.s1 = "No hay";
                $scope.colors1 = "red";
            }else{
                $scope.s1 = "Hay";
                $scope.colors1 = "#90EE90";
            }

            if (data.s2 == 1){
                $scope.s2 = "No hay";
                $scope.colors2 = "red";
            }else{
                $scope.s2 = "Hay";
                $scope.colors2 = "#90EE90";
            }               

            if (data.s3 == 1){
                $scope.s3 = "No hay";
                $scope.colors3 = "red";
            }else{
                $scope.s3 = "Hay";
                $scope.colors3 = "#90EE90";
            }

            if (data.s4 == 1){
                $scope.s4 = "No hay";
                $scope.colors4 = "red";
            }else{
                $scope.s4 = "Hay";
                $scope.colors4 = "#90EE90";
            }*/

                });
        });

    }
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [The `center` element is obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#center), use CSS instead. And it seems you are using angularjs or something like that, please add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: Will do on the CSS part, but for now we have to make it work as is, since there is a tight deadline. I have added the tag for Angular.js thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is you missed the quotes and brackets in your bgcolor attribute. Also, I think `style="background-color:{{var}}"` is more appropriate.

```
<center>
    Tarjeta: {{idt}}, Version: {{ver}}
    <table border="1px" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=400>
            <center>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="{{colors1}}"><h2>{{s1}}</h2></td>
            <td bgcolor="{{colors2}}"><h2>{{s2}}</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="{{colors3}}"><h2>{{s3}}</h2></td>
            <td bgcolor="{{colors4}}"><h2>{{s4}}</h2></td>
        </tr>
            </center>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: We tried changing that, but the result was that the background didn´t change, I mean it just stayed gray, which means that it wasn´t reading the value from the script

Comment: Check the js fiddle, You can see there that it works. Also check if your ng-app, ng-controller and other basic settings are correct. And if you imported angular.js in your html code.

Comment: It was, since we were using Json, the values we were compairing were strings oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend modifying your data model a bit:

data argument of socket message callback in format:

```
{
  idt: <value>
  ver: <ver>
  values: [Array of s* values] i.e. [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, ...]        
}
```

This would allow two big advantages:

1. You don't restrict the number of values displayed by your implementation.
2. You decouple your view logic (colors) from your service layer and reduce the amount of data across the wire.

So, using this data model would give you the following implementation:

**JS:**

```
$scope.socket.on("message", function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<center>
    Tarjeta: {{data.idt}}, Version: {{data.ver}}
    <table border="1px" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=400>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in data.values">
            <td ng-if="value === 1" bgcolor="red"><h2>No hay</h2></td>
            <td ng-if="value !== 1" bgcolor="#90EE90"><h2>hay</h2></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

**ALSO:** In your post, you have `bgcolor={colors1}` which would break your markup.  Instead use `bgcolor="{{colors1}}"` -- double quotes and double braces added.

**EDIT:** Sorry, just noticed that your presentation *IS* decoupled from your service layer :)

Comment: we tried the quotes and braces, it didn't work, it just left the squares in the background color of the background to the squares. Thanks a lot for the response.